# Same variable used in 2 nested loops can have different values?

Tags: variables, for-loop, int

First of all I want to say hi to you all!

I'm a self-taught, beginner programmer, started with C, and started to really enjoy this.

Today I've stumbled upon something very interesting and intriguing at the same time in one of my test programs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define NUMBERS 6
#define BALLS 6

int main()
{
int x, y, z, numbers[BALLS];

for (x = 0; x < BALLS; x++)
    numbers[x] = -1;

srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

puts("\t\tTHE AMAZING LOTTERY\n\n");
printf("Have you ever won at a lottery?\n");
printf("You can try your luck now! %c\n\n" , 2);
printf("Quick, write down 6 numbers and then press \"Enter\"");
getchar();

for (y = 0; y < BALLS; y++)
{



/* This is the intriguing part*/

printf("%d\n", y);



  label:
    z = rand() % NUMBERS+1;

    for (y = 0; y < BALLS; y++)
    {
        if (z == numbers[y])
            goto label;
        else if (numbers[y] != -1)
            continue;
        else
        {
            numbers[y] = z;
            break;
        }
    }
}
printf("\n\nToday's numbers are %c\a ", 16);
for (x = 0; x < BALLS; x++)
    printf("%d, ", numbers[x]);

printf("\n\n\nWell...\n\t..tough luck buddy..");
printf("\n\n\n\tMaybe next time.. %c" , 15);
putchar('\n');
getchar();

return 0;
}
```

Tried in 3 different compilers, c4droid, code::blocks, and an online compiler. Same intriguing result.
Why does the same variable (y), declared only once but used in 2 nested loops, can hold different values without causing any problems?

I don't think this is a recommended practice, but... how come it works?

Answer (score 1):

your code is a bit complicate. it is not supposed to work like what you say unless you define the loop variables inside like "for (int y = 0; ...)" write a simple code and test it:

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("in first loop with i = %d\n",i);
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("in second loop with i = %d\n",i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice way to get into an ~infinite loop!

Yea, your program works as it should, but if you try to compile mine, you'll see that somehow the big for loop remembers where it left off and continue from there, not from where the small for loop ended.... although it uses the same exact variable....

Comment: you only have y in left side of the statements in loops and nowhere else, so nobody else changes it. the only reason it works can be like breaking from inner loop exactly when y has the value before entering the inner loop. put some printf or debug it to see how y changes ...